# In RXJS can you process data passed to a subject.next() before re-emitting it?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a feeling that this question is going to expose some serious naivety surrounding my understanding of observables but at the risk of looking foolish let me ask it anyway.

I would like to create an RXJS subject which does some operations on data passed into it before re-emitting it. Let me explain in longhand using a simplistic example.

#### e.g. rolling `distinctUntilChanged` into the source observable

In the code below, I have one observable which is updated every time that an event happens that could alter the window's `active` state.

However in order to avoid emitting duplicate values I have a second observable which filters only distinct values before emitting them.

```js
export class MyService {
  activeValue$ = new Subject<boolean>()
  active$: Observable<boolean>

  constructor() {

    // setup an observable that only emits *changed* 
    // values of the active value
    this.active$ = this.activeValue$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )

    // Listen to multiple cues for things that might alter active state
    window?.addEventListener('focus', () => this.setActiveValue(true))
    window?.addEventListener('click', () => this.setActiveValue(true))
    window?.addEventListener('hide', () => this.setActiveValue(false))
    window?.addEventListener('blur', () => this.setActiveValue(false))

  }
}
```

### Can I combine the two observables into a single observable?

This example is so simple as to be trivial but it illustrates the goal which is to pre-process the data going into an observable via `.next()` before re-emitting it.

I would ideally like to be able to write code that looks something like:

```js
export class MyService {

  active$: Subject<boolean>

  constructor() {

    // This (for many reasons) doesn't work but it kind of shows what 
    // I'm hoping for...
    this.active$ = new Subject<boolean>().pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    ...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you've done in your first example code is the typical way to achieve this:

- define a private subject for pushing values
- spin off a public observable to apply any "clean up" logic
- consumers access the public observable to receive the "clean" emissions

> Can I combine the two observables into a single observable?

From your desired code:

```js
    this.active$ = new Subject<boolean>().pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
```

This could work... BUT, you don't maintain a reference to the subject, so you aren't able to push values (subject.next()).  So you do need both a subject and an observable.

You might find it cleaner to initialize your observable outside the constructor as you are doing with your subject:

```js
export class MyService {
  private activeValue$ = new Subject<boolean>()
  public active$ = this.activeValue$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged())

  constructor() {
    // Listen to multiple cues for things that might alter active state
    window?.addEventListener('focus', () => this.setActiveValue(true))
    window?.addEventListener('click', () => this.setActiveValue(true))
    window?.addEventListener('hide', () => this.setActiveValue(false))
    window?.addEventListener('blur', () => this.setActiveValue(false))
  }

  setActiveValue(value: boolean) {
    this.activeValue$.next(value)
  }
}
```

Now... The above assumes you actually need a subject to "manually" push values through.  If you can get your events via other observables, you don't need a subject at all.  In the case of events, you may choose to use [`fromEvent`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent):

```js
export class MyService {

  public active$ = merge(
     fromEvent(window, 'focus').pipe(mapTo(true)),
     fromEvent(window, 'click').pipe(mapTo(true)),
     fromEvent(window, 'hide').pipe(mapTo(false)),
     fromEvent(window, 'blur').pipe(mapTo(false)),
  ).pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    shareReplay(1) // add this if you want subscribers to receive the
  )                // most recent emission upon subscription which
                   // is often desired in angular services
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a beautiful solution for this. One thing you could do is to have a second "staging" `Subject`. You subscribe to this Observable and add any kind of transformations or filters inside this pipe. Inside `subscribe` you could then push the values directly to `$active`.

```
let active$ = new Subject()
let staging = new Subject()
staging.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(val => {
  active$.next(val)
})


active$.subscribe(console.log)
```

But I think it would be better to just use Observables. Create a `source$` Subject and another Observable.

```
let source$ = new Subject()
let active$ = source$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(val => {
  active$.next(val)
})
```

Afterwards use `active$` everywhere to subscribe and `source$` to push new values.